# Remove OAuth Social Providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I accidentally added the Google Social Login with OAuth to Aws Cognito, and now every time I run amplify pull I receive this message -

> "You've opted to allow users to authenticate via Google. If you
> haven't already, you'll need to go to
> https://developers.google.com/identity and create an App ID."

I would like to remove the Google Social Login so I could pull without inputting the client ID, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From the command line, run: `amplify update auth`
2. Select: `❯ Update OAuth social providers`.
3. Arrow-down to "Google", and hit the space bar to deselect it, so that `❯◉ Google` becomes `❯◯ Google`.
4. Hit enter.
5. Run `amplify push`.